# Android - Checking Internet Connection as soon as application is opened

Tags: android

I'm trying to check if the user has net connection as soon as he opens the application, but I'm facing few difficulties. i.e., as soon as the application is opened and when it goes to this try block :

```
try {
                      new DefaultHttpClient().execute(requestForTest);
                      responded = true;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        responded = false;
                    }
```

responded always returns false,but however when the user clicks on a button to come back to the main /activity responded returns true.

In simple words responded returns true only when the user comesback to the main screen/activity after pressing a button, otherwise it returns false. Where am I going wrong?. Your help would be appreciated thankyou !

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boolean check=chkNetworkStatus(getBaseContext());
    if (check==true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you have a working internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //do something

            }

    public static boolean chkNetworkStatus(Context context) {
            boolean result = false;

            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                   for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
                   HttpGet requestForTest = new HttpGet("http://m.google.com");
                   try {
                          new DefaultHttpClient().execute(requestForTest);
                          responded = true;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            responded = false;
                        }
                   }
                }
            }.start();
            boolean isOnline = isOnline(context);
            if(responded && isOnline){
                result = true;
            } else {
                result = false;
            }

            Log.e("","responded : "+responded);
            return result;
        }

    public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

Log : 




[As Soon as application starts]
    05-07 13:41:00.121: E/(10640): responded : false
    05-07 13:41:00.313: D/libEGL(10640): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
    05-07 13:41:00.321: D/(10640): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb97d4600, tid 10640
    05-07 13:41:00.409: D/libEGL(10640): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
    05-07 13:41:00.409: D/libEGL(10640): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
    [after clicking a button to get back to the first activity]
    05-07 13:41:23.553: E/(10640): responded : true
    05-07 13:41:23.689: D/dalvikvm(10640): GC_CONCURRENT freed 239K, 9% free 19341K/21156K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 35ms
    05-07 13:41:23.689: D/dalvikvm(10640): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
    05-07 13:41:23.689: D/dalvikvm(10640): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
    05-07 13:41:23.689: D/dalvikvm(10640): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
    05-07 13:41:23.765: W/EGL_emulation(10640): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    05-07 13:41:24.033: I/System.out(10640): {"result" : "true"}
```

Comment: @yuvaツ I have posted my log !

Answer (score 0):

use this method to check net connectivity:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                || connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            if (connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                    || connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
            {

                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;

    }
```

Comment: Thankyou but this method returns true if it is connected to a router but what if the router is not connected to the internet !

Comment: @user3458008 its return false simply

Comment: It still returns true and not false because the mobile is connected to the router !

Answer (score 0):

To check internet connection status, first in your manifest you have to write :

```
 <!-- Internet Permissions -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <!-- Network State Permissions -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then i use this method to check connection status :

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = 
        (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    }

    NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
    if (info == null) {
        return false;
    }

    for (NetworkInfo anInfo : info) {
        if (anInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou but this method returns true if it is connected to a router but what if the router is not connected to the internet !